# How to make Kalman filter results equivalent to linear regression?

Tags: python, r, kalman-filter

Kalman filter appears to be a powerful estimator for linear problems. I understand one can tune the performance by adjusting parameters like process noise and measurement noise. Is it possible to adjust these parameters to make Kalman filter results converge to a classic linear regression? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4):

For the Kalman filter to replicate the results of a linear regression LR) you would have to cast your LR in state-space form:
$$ y_t = x_t'\beta_t + \epsilon_t$$
$$ \beta_t = \beta_{t-1} + \nu_t $$
and complete the specification with $\nu_t \sim N(0,\boldsymbol{0})$ which effectively makes the $\beta_t$ fixed and a diffuse prior $\beta_0 \sim N(0,\infty\times I)$ --which effectively says there is no a priori information about $\beta_0$. Then you feed the filter one observation at a time and when you reach the end of the sample you would have $\beta_t$ equal to the $\hat\beta$ computed by ordinary least squares.

Since you cannot set an "infinite" covariance matrix you might resort to an approximation, setting the covariance matrix to something suitably large, like $10^9\times I$; there are better but more complex ways of setting a diffuse prior.

Comment: Nice answer! This is good material for someone learning Kaplan filters generally